# Start-job resulting in null parameter

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, start-job

I'm trying to execute the following two lines of code in PowerShell v2.0 as a job, and am having trouble. I think I have the syntax right, but I can't get it to do what I think it should do, so I clearly am doing something wrong...

```
$report = <command line thing>
invoke-expression $report
```

These two lines work in PowerShell. But when I try to put it into a start-job command:

```
start-job -scriptblock {invoke-expression $report} -argumentlist $report | wait-job | receive-job
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because it is null.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpre
   ssionCommand
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

I understand that error as saying that the argument I'm passing the invoke-expression is null, but, I'd thought that by passing `$report` in the `-argumentlist` param, it'd get through?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access `$report` directly unless you do:

```
-scriptblock {param($report) invoke-expression $report}
```

The `param($report)` part captures the `$report` variable passed in via `-ArgumentList` and makes it available for use inside the scriptblock.